# MySQL Generate yearly reports month wise with staff name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've two tables user, and login_table

User table

```
 id   Name    status
----------------------
 1   Johan      1    
 2   Smith      1    
 .  .   .       .    
----------------------
```

Login table

```
 id     user_id   login_date    hours
-------------------------------------
 1        1       2017-01-01    8    
 2        1       2017-01-02    7    
 3        2       2017-01-03    12   
 4        2       2017-01-02    10   
 .        .       .             .     
-------------------------------------
```

Is there anyway we can fetch data like following?

```
index   user_id  name   Jan  Feb    Mar ....    Dec Total
---------------------------------------------------------
1         1     Johan   100  120    115 ....    120  455
1         2     Smith   100  110    120 ....    110  440
.         .     .        .    .      .           .    .
---------------------------------------------------------
```

We've already done this using PHP/MYSQL but takes much time to process and execute. Is there anyway we can directly fetch this from MySQL?

Comment: So the year is on the input right?

Comment: Yup, we'll pass year.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code (PHP, in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what `index` is, but the rest is a join, `group by`, and conditional aggregation:

```
select u.id, u.name,
       sum(case when month(l.login_date) = 1 then hours else 0 end) as jan,
       sum(case when month(l.login_date) = 2 then hours else 0 end) as feb,
       . . .,
       sum(hours)
from users u join
     login l
     on u.id = l.login_id
where l.login_date >= '2017-01-01' and l.login_date < '2018-01-01'
group by u.id, u.name;
```

Notes:

- The comparison on dates uses `>=` and `<` on purpose.  This is preferable because MySQL can use an index on the data.
- This assumes that you only want users who logged in during the year.  Otherwise, a left join is appropriate.
- I don't know what `index` is.  Perhaps you mean `status`?